# Deriving type class instances for case classes with exactly one field

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm working on a CSV parsing library ([tabulate](http://nrinaudo.github.io/tabulate/)). It uses simple type classes for encoding / decoding: encoding, for example, is done with instances of `CellEncoder` (to encode a single cell) and `RowEncoder` (to encode entire rows).

Using shapeless, I've found it pretty straightforward to automatically derive the following type class instances:

- `RowEncoder[A]` if `A` is a case class whose fields all have a `CellEncoder`.
- `RowEncoder[A]` if `A` is an ADT whose alternatives all have a `RowEncoder`.
- `CellEncoder[A]` if `A` is an ADT whose alternatives all have a `CellEncoder`.

The thing is, this last one turns out to be almost entirely useless in real life situations: an ADT's alternatives are almost always case classes, and I cannot derive a `CellEncoder` for a case class that has more than one field.

What I'd like to be able to do, however, is derive a `CellEncoder` for case classes that have a single field whose type has a `CellEncoder`. That would cover, for example, `Either`, scalaz's `\/`, cats' `Xor`...

This is what I have so far:

```
implicit def caseClass1CellEncoder[A, H](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, H :: HNil], c: CellEncoder[H]): CellEncoder[A] =
    CellEncoder((a: A) => gen.to(a) match {
      case h :: t => c.encode(h)
    })
```

This works fine when used explicitly:

```
case class Bar(xs: String)
caseClass1CellEncoder[Bar, String]
res0: tabulate.CellEncoder[Bar] = tabulate.CellEncoder$$anon$2@7941904b
```

I can't however get it to work implicitly, the following fails:

```
implicitly[CellEncoder[Bar]]
>> could not find implicit value for parameter e: tabulate.CellEncoder[Test.this.Bar]
```

I've also tried the following, with no more success:

```
implicit def testEncoder[A, H, R <: H :: HNil](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, R], c: CellEncoder[H]): CellEncoder[A] =
      CellEncoder((a: A) => gen.to(a) match {
        case h :: t => c.encode(h)
      })
```

Am I missing something? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little tricky to get the `H` inferred correctly, but you can do it with a `<:<` instance:

```
import shapeless._

case class CellEncoder[A](encode: A => String)

implicit val stringCellEncoder: CellEncoder[String] = CellEncoder(identity)
implicit val intCellEncoder: CellEncoder[Int] = CellEncoder(_.toString)

case class Bar(xs: String)

implicit def caseClass1CellEncoder[A, R, H](implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
  ev: R <:< (H :: HNil),
  c: CellEncoder[H]
): CellEncoder[A] = CellEncoder(
  (a: A) => ev(gen.to(a)) match {
    case h :: t => c.encode(h)
  }
)
```

(I've made up a simple `CellEncoder` for the sake of a complete working example.)

This works because `R` can be inferred when the compiler is looking for an `Generic.Aux[A, R]` instance, and can then guide the inference of `H` when looking for a value for `ev`.

Comment: I'll need to think long and hard about this, but I can confirm that it works. Coincidentally, I've been spending a lot of time in Circe's code to understand automatic type class derivation of case classes, so thanks both for that answer and Circe!

Comment: I'm struggling with the dual of this problem - writing a `CellDecoder` (`String => A`), since the `R <:< H :: HNil` isn't helpful in that context: the subtype relationship goes the wrong way, I have an `H :: HNil` and need an `R`. What's the etiquette for this, should I open a new question, amend this one, ... ?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo A new question would be appropriate.

Comment: Done, the new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576085/deriving-decoder-instances-of-case-classes-with-a-single-field).