# Deriving decoder instances of case classes with a single field

Tags: scala, shapeless

This question is tightly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563111/deriving-type-class-instances-for-case-classes-with-exactly-one-field), but not identical: it's the same context but the opposite problem.

I'm trying to derive a `CellDecoder[A]`, which is essentially a `String => A`, for `A`s that are case classes with a single field whose type has a `CellDecoder`.

In order to do this, I need to require:

- `A` to be transformable to `R`, where `R` is a subtype of `H :: HNil`.
- `H` to have `CellDecoder` instance.

That is:

```
implicit def caseClassCellDecoder[A, R, H](implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
  ev: R <:< (H :: HNil),
  d: CellDecoder[H]
): CellDecoder[A] = ???
```

The issue I'm having is that, once I've turned a `String` to an `H` through the relevant `CellDecoder` instance, I'm kind of stuck: `ev` allows me to turn an `R` into an `H :: HNil`, but not an `H :: HNil` into an `R`. Not having an `R`, I can't use my `Generic.Aux[A, R]` to get the final `A` instance.

It turns out that casting my `H :: HNil` into an `R` works, but I'm not sure why and can't convince myself that it'll always be the case.

I thought about requiring `R` to be strictly equal to `H :: HNil` (that is, to have a `R =:= HNil`), but then the implicits fail to resolve.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did use `=:=` instead of `<:<` however swapped the sides of `R` and `H::HNil` and that seemed to work:

```
case class CellDecoder[A](decode: String => A)

implicit val stringCellDecoder: CellDecoder[String] = CellDecoder(identity)

implicit def caseClassCellDecoder[A, R, H](implicit
                                           gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
                                           ev: (H :: HNil) =:= R,
                                           d: CellDecoder[H]
                                            ): CellDecoder[A] = CellDecoder(
  (str: String) => gen.from(ev(d.decode(str)::HNil))
)
```

So I was able to use it as follows:

```
case class TestDecoder(test: String)

def doDecode[A: CellDecoder](str: String): A = {
  implicitly[CellDecoder[A]].decode(str)
}

doDecode[TestDecoder]("encoded value")
```